# Display grid simulate flex-wrap

Tags: html, css

I have next grid:

```css
.item1 { grid-area: left; }
.item2 { grid-area: left2; }
.item3 { grid-area: main; }
.item4 { grid-area: right; }

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
    'left left main main main right'
    'left2 left2 main main main right';
  grid-gap: 10px;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  padding: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill);

}

.grid-container > div {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="item1">left1</div>
  <div class="item2">left2</div>
  <div class="item3">Main</div>  
  <div class="item4">Right</div>
</div>
```

How to apply for this grid a wrap functionality when the screen becomes small?
EX: when i will resize the screen the blocks should be aligned in a column (one above one).

Comment: media query? ...

Comment: @TemaniAfif, i saw that somebody apply this: `grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 186px);` and the grid became responsive. Why it does not work in my case?

Comment: because you have a more complex grid and you are defining area. How you want the responsive to behave?

Comment: @TemaniAfif, i described above the scope.

Comment: thne you will need media query for this, you cannot suddenly change the layout with a simple property to have *all* the block under each other

Answer (score 0):

```css
.item1 { grid-area: left; }
.item2 { grid-area: left2; }
.item3 { grid-area: main; }
.item4 { grid-area: right; }

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
    'left left main main main right'
    'left2 left2 main main main right';
  grid-gap: 10px;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  padding: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill);

}

.grid-container > div {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-size: 30px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .grid-container {
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="item1">left1</div>
  <div class="item2">left2</div>
  <div class="item3">Main</div>  
  <div class="item4">Right</div>
</div>
```

Try to add this part in your code.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .grid-container {
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
  }
}
```